# How to find the frequency of 2 word combination in string using ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've been using the code below to find the frequency of a given word in a string using Ruby.  My question is how I can adapt this to find the frequency of 2 words at a given time.  As example: "baa baa baa black sheep" should return...

```
{"baa baa"=>2, "baa black"=>1, "black sheep"=>1}
```

Code:

```
def count_words(string)
  words = string.split(' ')
  frequency = Hash.new(0)
  words.each { |word| frequency[word.downcase] += 1 }
  return frequency
end
```

Comment: There are more than 3 2-word combinations in your example above.  Do you care about order?

Comment: What are the other 2-word combinations?  I'd like most frequent first.

Comment: I mean the order.  You can have `black baa` too, but that would be going backwards through the string.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  I'm just trying to get forward through the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def count_words(string)
  words = string.downcase.split(' ')
  frequency = Hash.new(0)
  while words.size >= 2
    frequency["#{words[0]} #{words[1]}"] += 1
    words.shift
  end
  frequency
end
```

Comment: You should `downcase` before you `split`

Comment: Shouldn't it only return 1 result for "yes! yes!"?

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "baa baa baa black sheep"

count = Hash.new(0)
str.split.each_cons(2) do |words|
  count[ words.join(' ') ] += 1
end
count
# => {"baa baa"=>2, "baa black"=>1, "black sheep"=>1}
```

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know about each_cons